I want to display push notifications in a separate page in my app
I only want to display all the unread notifications in the messages page. Whenever I tap on a push notification I want to see the new notification along with other unread notifications in the page in all three states (foreground, background, terminated). It works fine for the foreground state. But when I tap on a push notification it in the background or terminated state, it displays all the received push notifications even though I already have read them.
I am storing a push notification in the shared preferences, whenever it receives. When I go to the messages page, the notifications get retrieved from the shared preferences and displays the unread notifications by checking the key 'read'. A notification is marked as read by tapping on it and this makes the 'read' key true and get removed from the notifications list.
This is code of the messages page.
  Future<void> _loadNotifications() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.reload().then((value) {
      List<String> storedNotifications = prefs.getStringList('notifications') ?? [];
      print("Stored Notifications - ${storedNotifications.length}");
      print(storedNotifications);
      // Decode stored notifications and add them to the list
      setState(() {
        notifications = storedNotifications.map((notification) {
          return jsonDecode(notification) as Map<String, dynamic>;
        }).toList();
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> _saveNotifications() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final List<String> jsonList = notifications.map((e) => jsonEncode(e)).toList();
    prefs.setStringList('notifications', jsonList);
  }

  Future<void> _removeReadNotifications(List<Map<String, dynamic>> notifications) async {
    notifications.removeWhere((element) => element['read'] == true);
    await _saveNotifications();
  }

  void _markAsRead(int index) async {
    setState(() {
      notifications[index]['read'] = true;
    });
    await _saveNotifications();
    print(notifications[index]);
    await _removeReadNotifications(notifications);
    print('!!!');
    print(notifications);
  }

This is the code for initializations and storing push notifications.
void _saveNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  List<String> notifications = prefs.getStringList('notifications') ?? [];
  print("Notifications length in save notification before ${notifications.length}");
  // Notification map
  Map<String, dynamic> notification = {
    'title': message.notification?.title ?? 'No Title',
    'body': message.notification?.body ?? 'No Body',
    'data': message.data,
    'timestamp': DateTime.now().toString(),
    'read': false
  };

  notifications.insert(0, jsonEncode(notification));
  print("Notifications length in save notification after ${notifications.length}");
  prefs.setStringList('notifications', notifications);
}

// Function to listen to background changes
Future _firebaseBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  if (message.notification != null) {
    _saveNotification(message);
    print('Some notification received in background...');
  }
}

await PushNotifications.initNotifications();

  // Initialize local notifications
  await PushNotifications().localNotiInit();

  // Listen to background notifications
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseBackgroundMessage);

  // On background notification tapped
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message.notification != null) {
      print('Background notification tapped');
      navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed('/message', arguments: message);
    }
  });

  // To handle foreground notifications
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    String payloadData = jsonEncode(message.data);
    print('Got a message in foreground');
    if (message.notification != null) {
      PushNotifications.showSimpleNotification(
          title: message.notification!.title!,
          body: message.notification!.body!,
          payload: payloadData);
    }
    _saveNotification(message);
  });

  // For handling in terminated state
  final RemoteMessage? message =
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
  if (message != null) {
    _saveNotification(message);
    print('Launched in terminated state');
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed('/message', arguments: message);
    });
  }


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
